# Problema ao fazer upload de arquivo

Tags: node.js

Estou realizando uma operação onde basicamente o cliente estará enviando as imagens que deseja para o servidor. Dessa forma o caminho que estou colocando para que ocorra o salvamento está correto, mas o usuário não estará salvando as fotos somente em um lugar. Essas fotos tem que ser salvas em diversos diretórios, ondo o usuário irá escolher.
Ex: tenho alunos e esses alunos possuem uma pasta para cada, assim essa pasta armazena diversas fotos e informações, se eu ir no perfil de um aluno e realizar um upload de uma foto dele, essa foto tem que ser salva em seu diretório.

E com isso entrou o problema. Estou usando o Multer para realizar essa operação de upload e nodejs.

Código multer:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            let caminhoFoto =  './public/lib/face-api/labels/Karen/'
            cb(null, caminhoFoto)
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
            }
        })
        
    var upload = multer({ storage })

    router.post('/uploadFacial', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.file, req.body)
        res.redirect('back')
    });
```

Front:

```
    <form action="/alunos/uploadFacial" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file d-inline" name="uploaded_file">
            <input type="text" value="{{aluno._id}}" class="form-control-file d-inline" name="aluno">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar foto" class="btn btn-default">         
        </div>
    </form>
```

Queria saber se de alguma forma é possível estar trocando esse local que é salvo o upload conforme a informação recebida do front ou se teria algum outro modo de estar se fazendo essa operação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após da uma pesquisa mais referente a esse assunto, consegui estar verificando oque tenho que fazer, até mesmo não sabia que isso seria possível, caso alguém souber o porque que isso ocorre, como que ocorre, para que eu possa estar entendendo um pouco mais relacionado a isso.

O código do front:

```
<form action="/alunos/uploadFacial/{{aluno._id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file d-inline w-50" name="uploaded_file">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar foto" class="btn btn-dark">         
            </div>
        </form>
```

Com isso estou passando na url do post o ID do aluno;

Multer:

```
    var multer  = require('multer')
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            let caminhoFoto =  './public/lib/face-api/labels/'+req.params.type
            cb(null, caminhoFoto)
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
            }
        })
        
    var upload = multer({ storage })

    router.post('/uploadFacial/:type', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.file, req.body)
        res.redirect('back')
    });
```

Após isso eu consigo estar recendo o valor TYPE no caminhoFoto, fazendo com que seja salvo no diretório de cada aluno.